# How can I split up a TEXT value based on a pattern and return the results in a table with TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this string, which is stored in a text field. The process of storing this information has since changed, but I need this "legacy" information in place.

```
23.06.17 - As per quote #8918.1. 7m Swing STage to Positon 1.
05.07.17 Stripped and rebuilt boat ready for positon 4 but rained off.
05.07.17 Stripped and rebuilt boat ready for positon 4 but rained off.
06.07.17 - Completion of Swing Stage to Positon 4.
21.07.17 - Built Access Tower to get acess to roof.
Got swing Stage onto roof.
No access to building unable to get parapit clamps and wire up.
21.07.17 - Built Access Tower to get acess to roof.
Got swing Stage onto roof.
No access to building unable to get parapit clamps and wire up.
```

How would I split this text by the date fields into a table of results, so for every new date, a new row (including the date) is shown. So in the above case, there would be 6 rows?

This is what I came up with as a proof of concept:

```
DECLARE @MEMO VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @MEMO = '23.06.17 test 1 24.06.17 test 2 25.06.17 test 3'

DECLARE @COUNTER INT
    SET @COUNTER=0

DECLARE @WORD VARCHAR(40)
    SET @WORD = ''

DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(10)
    SET @DATE = ''

DECLARE @LINE VARCHAR(500)
    SET @LINE = ''

WHILE @COUNTER <= LEN(@MEMO)+1 BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@MEMO, @COUNTER, 1) != ' ' BEGIN
        --Builds each character into a string.
        SET @WORD = @WORD + SUBSTRING(@MEMO, @COUNTER, 1)
        -- When we come across a space, assume the previous character is now a whole word.
    END ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@MEMO, @COUNTER, 1) = ' ' BEGIN
        IF @WORD NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]' BEGIN
            SET @LINE = @LINE + ' ' + @WORD
            SET @WORD = ''
        --If that word is a date string format then save it and reset.
        END ELSE IF @WORD LIKE '[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]' BEGIN
            SET @DATE = @WORD
            SET @LINE = ''
            SET @WORD = ''
            PRINT 'DATE: ' + @DATE
        END 
        IF LTRIM(@LINE) != '' BEGIN
            PRINT 'LINE: ' + LTRIM(@LINE)
        END
    END
    SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
END
```

but my results, are a bit off still. I can't figure out, how to only get the line to appear once it has been finished.

```
DATE: 23.06.17
LINE: test
LINE: test 1
DATE: 24.06.17
LINE: test
LINE: test 2
DATE: 25.06.17
LINE: test
LINE: test 3
```

The end goal is essentially this, for example

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ Date       ║ Value       ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 2017-06-23 ║ Test 1      ║
║ 2 ║ 2017-06-24 ║ Test 2      ║
║ 3 ║ 2017-06-25 ║ Test 3      ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: I wouldn't handle this in the database, I would export to a tool like Java (or maybe Perl) and do the work there.

Comment: The result will be used in a crystal report, so I either do it in that program or SQL. My first look for a solution though, will be with SQL. Thank you

Comment: Can you guarantee that the only place there will be a substring of the form `nn.nn.nn` (where `n` is a numeric character) is at the start of each entry? Also, should every entry start of the form `nn.nn.nn - `? 4 out of 6 of your example entries start this way with the dash as well, but the other 2 do not.

Comment: Yes, to the `nn.nn.nn` questions. The dashes afterwards can be treated as text.

Comment: is there a "newline" before each of your dates in the example?  char(13)+char(10) or just char(10) or just char(13)

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on a purpose build iTVF based on a recursive CTE.

Function code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ParseLegacyInfo
/* ===================================================================
Created to parse the text information from legacy system.
==================================================================== */
(
    @TextString VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
    WITH 
        cte_rSplit AS (
            SELECT 
                LineNum = 1,
                ParsedString = SUBSTRING(@TextString, 1, dl.DateLocation + 7),
                StringRemain = SUBSTRING(@TextString, dl.DateLocation + 8, 8000)
            FROM
                ( VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]%', STUFF(@TextString, 1, 8, '')), 0), 8000)) ) dl (DateLocation)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                LineNum = rs.LineNum + 1,
                ParsedString = SUBSTRING(rs.StringRemain, 1, dl.DateLocation + 7),
                StringRemain = SUBSTRING(rs.StringRemain, dl.DateLocation + 8, 8000)
            FROM            
                cte_rSplit rs
                CROSS APPLY ( VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]%', STUFF(rs.StringRemain, 1, 8, '')), 0), 8000)) ) dl (DateLocation)
            WHERE 
                rs.StringRemain LIKE '%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]%'
            )
    SELECT 
        rs.LineNum, 
        [Date] = CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(rs.ParsedString, 8), 4),
        TextValue = SUBSTRING(rs.ParsedString, 9, 8000)
    FROM
        cte_rSplit rs;
GO
```

Some test data...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LegacyInfo', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #LegacyInfo;

CREATE TABLE #LegacyInfo (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    TextData VARCHAR(8000) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #LegacyInfo (TextData) VALUES 
('23.06.17 - As per quote #8918.1. 7m Swing STage to Positon 1.
05.07.17 Stripped and rebuilt boat ready for positon 4 but rained off.
05.07.17 Stripped and rebuilt boat ready for positon 4 but rained off.
06.07.17 - Completion of Swing Stage to Positon 4.
21.07.17 - Built Access Tower to get acess to roof.
Got swing Stage onto roof.
No access to building unable to get parapit clamps and wire up.
21.07.17 - Built Access Tower to get acess to roof.
Got swing Stage onto roof.
No access to building unable to get parapit clamps and wire up.'),
('23.06.17 - As per quote #8918.1. 7m Swing STage to Positon 1.
05.07.17 Stripped and rebuilt boat ready for positon 4 but rained off.
05.07.17 Stripped and rebuilt boat ready for positon 4 but rained off.
06.07.17 - Completion of Swing Stage to Positon 4.
21.07.17 - Built Access Tower to get acess to roof.
Got swing Stage onto roof.
No access to building unable to get parapit clamps and wire up.
21.07.17 - Built Access Tower to get acess to roof.
Got swing Stage onto roof.
No access to building unable to get parapit clamps and wire up.'),
('31.12.17 - This is just a test...'),
('01.01.17 - Line 1
Some other text following line 1.
22.02.17 - Line 2
More stuff about line 2.');
```

The final query...

```
SELECT 
    li.id, LineNum, Date, TextValue
FROM
    #LegacyInfo li
    CROSS APPLY dbo.ParseLegacyInfo(li.TextData);
```

Results... (note: the original carage returns and line feeds are still in tact.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT - Corrected for Typo**

One approach is to parse the string into words, and then reconstruct.

I used a Table-Valued Function to split the string, but easily converted to an in-line approach (no udf)

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Memo varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'23.06.17 - As per quote #8918.1. 7m Swing STage to Positon 1.
05.07.17 Stripped and rebuilt boat ready for positon 4 but rained off.
05.07.17 Stripped and rebuilt boat ready for positon 4 but rained off.
06.07.17 - Completion of Swing Stage to Positon 4.
21.07.17 - Built Access Tower to get acess to roof.
Got swing Stage onto roof.
No access to building unable to get parapit clamps and wire up.
21.07.17 - Built Access Tower to get acess to roof.
Got swing Stage onto roof.
No access to building unable to get parapit clamps and wire up.')
,(2,'23.06.17 test 1 24.06.17 test 2 25.06.17 test 3')


;with cte as (
        Select A.ID
              ,B.*
         From  @YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                        Select *
                              ,Flg = case when RetVal like '[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]' then 1 else 0 end
                              ,Grp = sum(case when RetVal like '[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]' then 1 else 0 end) over( Order By RetSeq)
                        From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](replace(Memo,char(13)+char(10),' '),' ')
                     ) B
)
Select ID
      ,LineNbr = Grp
      ,Date    = convert(date,RetVal,4)
      ,Text    = Stuff((Select Top 1000 ' ' +RetVal From cte Where ID=A.ID and Grp=A.Grp and Flg=0 Order By RetSeq For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
 From  cte A
 Where Flg=1
 Order By ID,Grp
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The Parse/Split UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```